# Error When Add new DataColumn in DataTable?

Tags: c#, ado.net

how to add new column in new DataTable But Erorr

```
private void LoadtoList()
{
    SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmpSign", _constr);
    dt = new DataTable("CCTVTable");
    sa.Fill(dt);

    dtpass = new DataTable("CCTVpassword");
    SqlDataAdapter sa2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PASSWORD FROM Emp e WHERE e.EmpID IN ('f2123', 'f2124', 'f2126', 'rt015', 'f2133')",
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaraburiEmp"].ConnectionString);
    sa2.Fill(dtpass);
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
    dc = dtpass.Columns["password"];
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
}
```

---

> Column 'PASSWORD' already belongs to
>   another DataTable.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentException: Column
>   'PASSWORD' already belongs to another
>   DataTable.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 1040:        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
Line 1041:        dc = dtpass.Columns["password"];
Line 1042:        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
Line 1043:    }
Line 1044:}
```

Comment: wish there was as "twit filter" feature on SO :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explanation in exception message: "**Column 'PASSWORD' already belongs to another DataTable**"

Which basically means that You cannot reuse this column. You have to create new one (similar to this password column) and then add it to table.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must remove column from dtpass table:

```
...
DataColumn dc = dtpass.Columns["password"];
dtpass.Columns.Remove("password");
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Comment: hello, the value nothing in Datatable in object dt ?

Answer (score 0):

error itself says that "**Column 'PASSWORD' already belongs to another DataTable**" .Because you are already use password in DataTable.

same thing as in [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) , you cant able to add multiple data column with same name in a single table :)

Comment: Sorry, i have 2 table

    DataTable dt;
    DataTable dtpass;

Comment: dt.Columns.Add("password", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < dtpass.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["password"] = dtpass.Rows[i]["password"].ToString();
        }

Comment: when you do SqlDataAdapter sa2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PASSWORD FROM Emp e WHERE e.EmpID IN ('f2123', 'f2124', 'f2126', 'rt015', 'f2133')",
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaraburiEmp"].ConnectionString);
    sa2.Fill(dtpass);
PASSWORD  is set to datatable.how can you add again to same dt again ?